# How to implement the same sorting behaviour with custom header template

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

My question is similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745611/replacing-headertext-with-headertemplate-in-templatefield) but the answer does not work for me as a linkbutton behaves differently than normal sorting headings.

Our website uses `Server.Transfer` to hide different page access under a unique URL. Clicking on a `asp:LinkButton` will lead to the front page, and not just sorting the gridview.

When looking at the client page code, I observed that the tool tip of a normal column header looks like

```
javascript:__doPostBack("(grid view control id)","Sort$(field name)");
```

and on a column with custom header template using LinkButton, it is

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
    "(link button control id)", "", true, "", "", false,true);
```

I think the difference is the cause.

How to make them behave the same?

**Update**

I noticed that for a `asp:Button` rather than link button, the javascript click event calls

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
    "(button control id)", "", true, "", "", false, false);
```

And it is not leading to the front page.

So it seems I only need to set up so that the link button does not do a client side submit. But what is the best way to do so?

Comment: Have you want to prevent postback when `LinkButton` is clicked? AFAIK, `LinkButton` always having `clientSubmit = true` because it renders as anchor tag, where `Button` has `UseSubmitBehavior` property to control `clientSubmit` behavior as plain button or form submit button.

Comment: See my own answer below. I am not looking at prevent the postback, only wanted to disable the submit - but I do need to trigger the server side callback.

Comment: One other solution is to use CSS to render the `Button` tag like an `a` tag. But my CSS skills is not good enough to do this properly...

Comment: There was how to implement button like an anchor link in CSS: `.submitbutton { background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; border: none; color: blue; cursor: pointer; }` and putting `outline: none;` when the button being focused.

Comment: I think there are more to set... for example `:visited` and/or `:horver` states... as I know. It is not easy for me to get a comprehansive set of those details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following trick, I achieved this. As it is kind of hacking, I am still open to see better ways to solve it.

```
<asp:LinkButton href="javascript:void(0);" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:__doPostBack(this.id.replace(/_/g,'$'),'');" ...
```

Will prevent the submit and so not switch to the front page. It first set the `href` attribute such that it does not lead to anywhere, then in `OnClientClick` trigger the callback event of the `LinkButton`.

It resolves my problem, but it depends on the implementation details that ASP.NET generates IDs and event target identifiers. Are there any better solutions?